# Configurar arquivo web.config para projeto PHP em subdiretórios

Tags: php, htaccess, iis, web.config

Tenho um site em *php* em fase de teste em um diretório acima da raiz do site oficial. Para configurar as URL amigáveis (***remover a entensão .php***) é por *web.config*. Fiz uma regra que não funciona para os arquivos de subdiretórios. Ex: *produtos/algo* e *produto/algo*, só funciona nos arquivos da raiz tipo *empresa.php*. Ao acessar as páginas de produto e produtos tem se a mensagem "No input file specified."

http://www.exemplo.com.br/sitenovo/empresa = OK

http://www.exemplo.com.br/sitenovo/produtos/camisas = No input file specified.

Com a extensão php funciona normalmnte: http://www.exemplo.com.br/sitenovo/produtos.php/camisas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver dessa maneira: (Com asteriscos após a barra)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule 1p" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([a-z0-9-]+)/*"  ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />  
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/sitenovo/{R:1}.php/*" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>

            </rules>



        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```